# Having a hard time understanding how to manipulate date and time in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, math, time

I'm really not grasping how dates and times get formatted in PHP for use in mathematical equations. My goal is this;

Get a date and time from the database;

```
// Get array for times in
$sth = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM ledger ORDER BY ID");
$timeins = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $timeins[] = $r["timein"];
    //OR
    array_push($timeins, $r['timein']);
}
```

And then find the distance between the current time and the variable in the array, $timeins[0], and then put the minutes, hours, and days difference in separate simple variables for later use. These variables will be used on their own in if statements to find out if the person has passed certain amounts of time.

edit: the format of the dates being returned from the DB is in the default TIMESTAMP format for MySQL. E.g. 2018-08-06 17:38:37.

Comment: you can't just do maths with dates and expect things to work. Even something as simple as daylight saving will cause your code to at best do something weird for an hour, but will at worst bring down your server. Use a library for this, written by people who spent years making sure date maths actually does what it's supposed to.

Comment: You have to know the format that is being returned from the DB, then you can use the DateTime class to manipulate, see docs here: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to perform datetime operations in SQL, to get a difference between two datetime/timestamp values in days, hours, minutes...  We can use expressions in the SELECT list, to return the results as columns in the resultset.

Ditching the `SELECT *` pattern, and specifying an explicit list of expressions that we need returned:

```
$sql = "
SELECT t.id 
     , t.timein 
     , TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY    ,t.timein,NOW()) AS diff_days
     , TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR   ,t.timein,NOW()) AS diff_hours
     , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE ,t.timein,NOW()) AS diff_minute
  FROM ledger t
 ORDER BY t.id ";

if( $sth = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) ) {
  // execution successful 
  ...
} else {
  // handle sql error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class in PHP to do any date manipulation. You can convert a string representation of a MySQL format time to a PHP DateTime object using

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $mysqldate);
```

Also you can create a DateTime object representing the current time using the constructor with no argument:

```
$now = new DateTime();
```

To get the difference between two dates as a [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object, use the builtin diff method:

```
$diff = $now->diff($date);
```

As a complete example:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$mysqldate = '2018-04-03 12:30:01';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $mysqldate);
$diff = $now->diff($date);
$diff_days = (int)$diff->format('%a');
$diff_hours = $diff->h;
$diff_minutes = $diff->m;
echo "$diff_days days, $diff_hours hours, $diff_minutes minutes";
```

Output:

```
125 days, 9 hours, 4 minutes
```

Note that you have to use `$diff->format('%a')` rather than `$diff->d` to get the days between two dates, as `$diff->d` will not include the days in any months between the two dates (in this example it will return 3 for today being August 6).

Answer (score -1):

Using the DateTime Class in php is the best way to get accurate results.

```
$dateNow = new DateTime('now');
$dateIn = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s',  $timeins[0]);

$interval = $dateNow->diff($dateIn);

echo $interval->format('%d days, %h hours, %i minutes, %s seconds');
$deltaDays = $interval->d;
$deltaHours = $interval->h;
...
```

You have to make sure the input format for you DB date is correct, in this case, I assumed d-m-y H:i:s, and then you can output in any format you need as well, as shown in the date docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Format in the database is default timestamp added when the entry is created, e.g. 2018-08-06 17:38:37

I also get the following error from your code: 
Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on boolean in C:\....file.php on line 103

Comment: That is because the date object was not properly created with your DB values. You have to update the ::createFromFormat to match your DB, in this case 'Y-m-d H:i:s'